# How to expand input by advantages of DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have an input like this:

```
DEVP UNM DNUM
2000   2 16 
2010  AA 109 
3000   3 16
3010   3 97 
3070  AA 15
```

AA in the UNM column means one group ends.

There are two groups in the input. One group includes 2000(HEX) and 2010(HEX), and the other group includes 3000,3010 and 3070.

The number in the UNM column is the number of repetitions of this group

The Number in the DEVP column plus 128 when the group is repeating.

Below is the output  I wish to get.

```
DEVP  DNUM 
2000    16 
2010   109 
2080    16 
2090   109 
3000    16 
3010    97 
3070    15 
3080    16 
3090    97 
30F0    15 
3100    16 
3110    97 
3170    15
```

my code is below :

```
import pandas as pd
def twoDigitHex(number):
    return '%02x' % number

input1 = [{'DEVP': '2000', 'UNM': 2,'DNUM':16},
      {'DEVP': '2010', 'UNM': 'AA','DNUM':109},
      {'DEVP': '3000', 'UNM': 3,'DNUM':16},
      {'DEVP': '3010', 'UNM': 3,'DNUM':97},
      {'DEVP': '3070', 'UNM': 'AA','DNUM':15}]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(input1)
print(df1)
n = 0
t_data = []
out1=[]
i = 0
while i < len(df1.index.values):

    row_data = df1.loc[i].to_dict()
    t_data.append(row_data)

    if t_data[i]['UNM'] == 'AA':
        unm = int(t_data[n]['UNM'])
        for m in range(unm):

            for m0 in range(n, i + 1):
                devp0 = twoDigitHex(int(t_data[m0]['DEVP'], 16) + m * 128)

                out0={'DEVP':devp0.upper(),'DNUM':t_data[m0]['DNUM']}
                out1.append(out0)

        n = i + 1

    i = i + 1
df2 =pd.DataFrame(out1)
print(df2)
```

I have to handle the data row by row. I couldn't use any advantages of DataFrame.

Is there any way to make it more concise/more pythonic/more readable?

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Jason Cai